# Excel Macro to Find Cells that Contain "<6" in Columns with Header "n" and Replace the Adjacent Cell with "S"

Tags: microsoft-excel, macros

I'm relatively new to Excel VBA programming and I'm having problems generating a macro. My data looks something like this. In column A titled "N" I have counts going down several rows. If a count was between 1 and 6 I have the value "<6" in that cell. Otherwise the count is shown. In column B titled "%" I have the percent of that row relative to the total. This pattern repeats a variable number of times until the end of the table.

What I'm hoping to accomplish is that each time the value "<6" is found to change the value in the cell directly to the right to "S" (indicating the percentage is suppressed).

Comment: Did you look at making the formula in B: =IF(A2="<6","S",your_percentage_formula)?  This would be in B2; copy it down the column.  A macro isn't required (unless you want to do it with a macro just to learn how).

Comment: Hi Fixer1234 thank you for the suggestion but I am using Excel to suppress results from large tables that are generated by SAS. I have SAS calculating the percentages so I don't want to have to manually recalculating them. Otherwise your suggestion would be the easiest to implement. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the code chunk you need. You should try to integrate it to whatever code you have on your own.

```
Dim rng As Range, cell As Range
Set rng = Intersect(Range("A:A"), UsedRange)
If rng Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
For Each cell In rng.Cells
    If cell.Value = "<6" Then cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = "S"
Next
```